# adding the row values in the uitableview and display the added value in final row of the uitableview using objective c

Tags: objective-c

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    customcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[customcell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.finacialyear.text=[self->entries1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.term.text=[self->entries2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.balance.text=[self->entries3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return cell; 
}
```

have to add the rows values in the tableview cell and display in to the final row.can anyone suggest me how to do this in objective c.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add one extra row:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return <#rows you have now#> + 1;
}
```

Then you should return a different cell if you are in the last row:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (isLastRow) {
        return BalanceSumCell;
    } else {
        return customcell;
    }
}
```

Remember to name your classes with a capital first letter (`CustomCell` and not `customcell`).

If you want to do different calculations when the user selects a cell, you should do that in `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Keep track of user's selection and update the last cell as needed
}
```

In general, your question is broad and if you break it down to smaller problems you will find a lot of related answers to help you.

Good luck!